# C++でNSLogを出力させたい

Tags: c++, c, objective-c

https://fnet-tech.blogspot.com/2016/05/c-objective-c.html
を参考にしています。

TestObjectC.mm

```
#import "TestObjectC.h"
 
// ヘッダファイルではなく、ソースファイルで Objective-C クラスを宣言する
@interface ClassObjC : NSObject
 
+ (void)testingMethod;
 
@end
 
// 通常通りソースファイルで Objective-C クラスを実装する
@implementation ClassObjC
 
//--------------------------------------------------
// [Objective-C] テスト用
//--------------------------------------------------
+ (void)testingMethod
{
    NSLog(@"C++ から呼ばれました。");
}
 
@end
 
//==================================================
// [C++] Objective-C クラスのメソッドを呼ぶ
//==================================================
void TestObjectC::callObjC()
{
    [ClassObjC testingMethod];
}
```

TestObjectC.h

```
#ifndef TestObjectC_hpp
#define TestObjectC_hpp

//#include <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// C++ から呼ばれるクラスを宣言する
class TestObjectC
{
    public:
        // C++ から呼ばれる関数
        static void callObjC();
};


#endif /* TestObjectC_hpp */
```

この２ファイルを追加し、この時点ではビルドが通ることを確認しました。
このあと、C++クラスから上記を読んでみようと考え、以下を追加しました。

NSLogCall.h

```
#ifndef NSLogCall_hpp
#define NSLogCall_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
class NSLogCall {
public:
    static NSLogCall* getInstance();
    void printLog();
protected:
    NSLogCall();
    ~NSLogCall();
private:
    static NSLogCall*    sInstance;
};
#endif /* NSLogCall_hpp */
```

NSLogCall.cpp

```
#include "NSLogCall.h"
//#include "TestObjectC.h"※


NSLogCall* NSLogCall::sInstance = nullptr;
// コンストラクター
NSLogCall::NSLogCall()
{
}
// デストラクター
NSLogCall::~NSLogCall()
{
}

NSLogCall* NSLogCall::getInstance()
{
    if(NSLogCall::sInstance == nullptr){
        sInstance = new NSLogCall();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

void NSLogCall::printLog() {
//    TestObjectC::callObjC();※
}
```

※箇所を解除したのですが、
Format argument not an 'NSStrting'
のエラーが追加したファイル以外(NSObjCRuntime.h)で出ています。
C++で使えないNSStringが影響しているとは思うのですが、C++からNSLogを使用する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C/C++の`#import`ディレクティブを含むヘッダーは、標準C/C++用のソースファイル (.c/.cpp) からはインクルードしてはいけません（できません）。

"TestObjectC.h" からは`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`を除去したうえで、
Objective-C++のソースファイル側にてインポートとインクルードを記述します。

ちなみに`NSLog()`関数自体は、Objective-C/C++のソースファイル (.m/.mm) 内であれば、CやC++の関数内でも直接呼び出せます。ただし`@autoreleasepool`ブロックを使うべきです。

```
// TestObjectC.mm
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "TestObjectC.h"

void TestObjectC::callObjC() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"C++ から呼ばれました。");
    }
}
```

```
// xxx.m or xxx.mm
#include "xxx.h"

void printUtf8StringByNSLog(const char* utf8) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: utf8];
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }
}

void printUtf16StringByNSLog(const char16_t* utf16) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%S", utf16);
    }
}
```

```
// xxx.h
#pragma once

// C++ ではなく C コードから利用する場合は <uchar.h> のインクルードが必要。

extern void printUtf8StringByNSLog(const char* utf8);
extern void printUtf16StringByNSLog(const char16_t* utf16);
```

`NSLog()`には`const char*`を出力するための`%s`書式もありますが、UTF-8マルチバイト文字列には対応していません。

- [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

余談ですが、`new`に対応する`delete`を記述しないような、中途半端なシングルトンの書き方は避けるべきです。
C++11以降では、関数内の`static`ローカル変数の初期化はスレッドセーフとなることが保証されるので、シングルトンの実装には`static`ローカル変数を使う手もあります。

- [ブロックスコープを持つstatic変数初期化のスレッドセーフ化 - cpprefjp C++日本語リファレンス](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/static_initialization_thread_safely.html)

**2021-05-12追記：**
`<uchar.h>`は、C11の`char16_t`エイリアス型を利用する際に必要となるヘッダーで、もし`char16_t`を使わないのであれば、Cであっても特にインクルードする必要はありません。
macOS上でXcodeを利用されているものだと仮定しますが、現状、Apple ClangのC11対応は不完全で、UTF-16リテラルの`u`プレフィックスや、C99の`uint_least16_t`型は使えるものの、Xcode 12.4時点でも`<uchar.h>`は実装されていないようです。
C++では`char16_t`が組み込み型であるために、利用にあたって特に何かインクルードする必要はありません。

- https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char16_t
- https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal
- https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer
- https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types
- https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

以下を事前に記述しておけば、一応Cでもコンパイルできるようになります。

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint_least16_t char16_t;
#endif
```

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。まずは上記を参考に実装してみました。C++でNSLogが出力されることを確認できました。次にCで試してみたところ、 <uchar.h> は見つからないと言われてしまいました。一旦、C++でログ出力関数をラップしてみて試してみたいと思います。その他のアドバイスについても一つずつ確認していきたいと思います。

Comment: お恥ずかしながら、初めて@autoreleasepoolというものを知りました。まだきちんと理解出来ていないのですが、このアノテーションのブロックを抜けるときにメモリ解放が実施されるもの・・・という認識です。

Comment: @kankomu 
`<uchar.h>`と`char16_t`に関して、本文に追記しました。なお、最も役に立った回答には、「承認済み」のマークをお願いします。
「ツアー - スタック・オーバーフロー」 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour
「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー」 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers